# Create JSF xhtml View (OnFly) from database

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-2.2

I am working on a JSF project   where it is required to load the (xhtml)view from database. For example, in my database I have a table named `item_view_mapping` consist two columns one for the unique identification and another for storing the xhtml content, what my requirement is that I will load those view onFly as per the user request. Currently I have 5-6 templates and i am using `<ui:include src="template_name.xhtml"></ui:include>` , looking for a solution where instead of static xhtml page I can load templates or page content from database. I have tested in every possible way. The problem is if the content consist jsf tags or any expression it simply not working as it should. Googled a lot and found this hint custom `ResourceHandlerImpl`, but I have no clue in my case how do I use that.I am using jsf 2.2.